# Issue with Impala Build

Tags: hadoop, hbase, impala

I am trying to build impala on ubuntu-20.04 using https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IMPALA/Building+Impala .

I am able to see HDFS, HIVE, HBase, Ranger components are downloaded but the build was failing with "`Could not get one or more nodes`"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXypX.png)

For building purpose i have used the below command,

```
./buildall.sh -noclean -notests -format
```

While build it has successfully started HDFS,HIVE, Hbase, Zookeeper services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSAgt.png)

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I don't recall Impala requiring Hbase. Also, linked page says Ubuntu 20 isn't supported (but also isn't updated since 2016). So, perhaps the Impala github repo has more recent instructions

Comment: Thanks for reply @OneCricketeer, Yes linked page says ubuntu 20 isn't supported but as I have to execute bootstrap_system.sh file which mentions support for ubuntu 20

Comment: For reference you can use below link 
https://github.com/apache/impala/blob/master/bin/bootstrap_system.sh

Yes, I also think so that impala didn't require Hbase but the build itself create a mini cluster with HDFS, Hive, Zookeeper, Hbase, Ranger like services. And while checking the status of master & region server my build is failing.
I have done some changes in check-hbase-nodes.py as a reference ticket IMPALA_4684 (The same issue i was facing) from below link but no luck.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-4156?jql=text%20~%20%22hbase-nodes.py%22

Comment: I've only used CDH, where Impala comes out of the box... There should be an email list for Impala where you can ask questions to the developers that more commonly build from scratch